# UIWebView loadRequest not firing in custom function

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiwebview

First, thanks to everyone that takes the time to answer questions. I have gotten so many quick answers to problems over the years from StackOverflow.

I'm new to Object C and iOS programming, but starting with what I think should be a super simple app. It receives a push notification (which works fine) and redirects to a webpage when it has figured out its appid.

The problem is that the while I can get my UIWebView to loadRequest in the viewDidLoad, the same code will not execute in another function.

Here's the code:

AppDelegate.m

```
//  UFAppDelegate.m
#import "UFAppDelegate.h"
#import "UFViewController.h"

@implementation UFAppDelegate
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Add registration for remote notifications
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
     (UIRemoteNotificationType)(UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];   
    return YES;
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)devToken {

    // ....

    NSString *urlString = @"http://www.google.com";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSLog(@"Navigating to URL: %@", url);
    UFViewController *theview = [[UFViewController alloc] init];
    [theview handleOpenURL:url];
}

@end
```

ViewController.h:

```
//  UFViewController.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UFViewController : UIViewController
- (void)handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url;
@end
```

ViewController.m:

```
//  UFViewController.m
#import "UFViewController.h"

@interface UFViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *UFHWebView;
- (void)handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url;
@end

@implementation UFViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"UFViewController.viewDidLoad started");

    // This block that assigns the url and loads it works perfectly here... but not down below.        
    NSString *urlString = @"http://search.yahoo.com/";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [_UFHWebView loadRequest:requestObj];

    NSLog(@"UFViewController.viewDidLoad completed");
}

- (void)handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url
{
    NSLog(@"UFViewController.handleOpenURL started");
    NSLog(@"url = %@",url);

    // The below loadRequest does not load!
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [_UFHWebView loadRequest:requestObj];
    NSLog(@"UFViewController.handleOpenURL completed");
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Error - %@", error);        
}

- (BOOL) webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    return  YES;
}

@end
```

When run as coded here, the yahoo page shows from the loadRequest in the didload, but the handleOpenURL one still does not fire. If I comment out the loadRequest out of viewDidLoad, a blank page shows up and the handleOpenURL still does not fire.

Here's the debug sequence. viewDidLoad fires and completes before receiving the AppID and manually firing handleOpenURL:

```
2013-12-12 15:28:32.606 UF[5896:60b] UFViewController.viewDidLoad started
2013-12-12 15:28:32.608 UF[5896:60b] UFViewController.viewDidLoad completed
2013-12-12 15:28:32.765 UF[5896:60b] Navigating to URL: http://www.google.com
2013-12-12 15:28:32.769 UF[5896:60b] UFViewController.handleOpenURL started
2013-12-12 15:28:32.773 UF[5896:60b] url = http://www.google.com
2013-12-12 15:28:32.775 UF[5896:60b] UFViewController.handleOpenURL completed
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: are you sure, you have conformed to protocol `UIWebViewDelegate` in right place ?

Comment: How is `theView` being added to the window/navController? You've indicated missing code at the beginning of the method, but not at the end

Comment: Hi Rich-- "theview" is being referenced using this line in the appdelegate: "UFViewController *theview = [[UFViewController alloc] init];" ... and yes, there is no code after that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you have just one instance of `UFViewController` here?

`-didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` initializes a new web view controller in a local variable, but I can't see how it's getting shown to the user - you aren't doing anything with the vc once it's created.

Here's what I think might be happening:

1. App starts. You have an instance of `UFViewController` in a storyboard. It loads, its `-viewDidLoad` is called, the log statements print and the webview loads correctly.
2. A little later, the `-didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:` method is called. This instantiates a `UFViewController`, and calls the `-handleOpenUrl` method on it.  The `-handleOpenURL` log methods fire. However, this controller has not been loaded into the view hierarchy,  so its view is never instantiated, and its `-viewDidLoad` is never called. 
   This means that the webview that the `-loadRequest:` is being called on is `nil`. In Objective-C, it is valid to send a message to `nil`- unlike most other languages, no error or exception will be thrown. Instead, absolutely nothing happens, hence no web load.
   The `UFViewController` in `-handleOpenUrl` is only referred to by a local variable within the method, so when the method completes, the last strong reference to it vanishes and it is released.

To check this is correct:

-`NSLog(@"%@",[self description]);` in your vc methods - this will log the address of the objects and tell you whether they are the same.

-`NSLog` the web controller's view, to check whether it's `nil` in `handleOpenURL`

To solve your problem, I suggest using an `NSNotification` posted by the `AppDelegate` and listened for by the `UFViewController` that is fully instantiated. So in the vc you'd do:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleRegistration:) name:@"HandleRegistrationNotification" object:nil];
```

and then implement the `handleRegistration` method:

```
-(void)handleRegistration:(NSNotification*)notification
{
     //your handleOpenUrl code 
}
```

and also

```
-(void)dealloc
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]removeObserver:self name:@"HandleRegistrationNotification" object:nil];
}
```

(this bit is important because otherwise you may get a crash when the vc is dealloc'd)

Then, in the `-didRegisterForRemoteNotifications:` method:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]postNotificationName:@"HandleRegistrationNotification" object:nil];
```

If you need to pass any information through the notification (eg urls) you can use the `object` parameter - this is accessible in the method called on the vc via the `object` property of the `NSNotification` parameter.

Full docs on notifications in Objective-C can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Notifications/Introduction/introNotifications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000043i).

Some minor points - it's generally a bad idea to call your view controllers things like `theView` rather than `theViewController` since other people (or you in 6 months time) will end up thinking they're `UIView` s. Also the webview property should not start with a capital letter- that's generally only used for class names.

Comment: Fnatastic answer, thank you! I am about to try your suggestions. Thank you for the detailed explanation of the firing sequence... that goes a long way to understanding until I have time to sit down with a book. My intention of doing "UFViewController *theview = [[UFViewController alloc] init]; / [theview handleOpenURL:url];" was to get a pointer to the already created ViewController and call its handleOpenURL... because I actually need the AppID which (not included in the code example) is figured out in the didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken function.

Comment: Rich, your evaluation was correct! They are two different objects. <UFViewController: 0x1669f8f0> and the second one <UFViewController: 0x16595610> reported when manually calling my handleOpenURL function. Ideally in didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken I would just like to get a handle to the already created WebView and call its handleOopenURL function. But I am going to try your other suggestions as well and see if I can't get there that way. Thank you!

Comment: [self _UFHWebView.handleOpenURL:url]; ??

Answer (score 0):

This should be called, "How to call a storyboard viewcontroller method from the appdelegate". And the answer is:

in AppDelegate.m:

```
#import "UFViewController.h"
...
UFViewController *rootViewController = (UFViewController*)self.window.rootViewController;
[rootViewController handleOpenURL:url];
```

In my code snippets above, this means replacing these lines

```
UFViewController *theview = [[UFViewController alloc] init];
[theview handleOpenURL:url];
```

with the ones above. The difference is my original code instantiates a new UFViewController object into a local variable, while the correct code just gets a handle to the view controller already created in the storyboard and calls its method.